# Extracting values from R table within grouped values

Tags: r

I have the following table ordered group by first, second and name.

```
    myData <- structure(list(first = c(120L, 120L, 126L, 126L, 126L, 132L, 132L), second = c(1.33, 1.33, 0.36, 0.37, 0.34, 0.46, 0.53), 
    Name = structure(c(5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Benzene", 
    "Ethene._trichloro-", "Heptene", "Methylamine", "Pentanone"
    ), class = "factor"), Area = c(699468L, 153744L, 32913L, 
    4948619L, 83528L, 536339L, 105598L), Sample = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("PO1:1", "PO2:1", "PO4:1"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("first", "second", "Name", 
    "Area", "Sample"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Within each group I want to extract the area that correspond to the specific sample. Several groups don´t have areas from the samples, so if the sample is´nt detected it should return "NA".Ideally, the final output should be a column for each sample.

I have tried the ifelse function to create one column to each sample:

`PO1<-ifelse(myData$Sample=="PO1:1",myData$Area, "NA")`

However this doesn´t takes into account the group distribution. I want to do this, but within the group. Within each group (a group as equal value for first, second and Name columns) if sample=PO1:1, Area, else NA.

For the first group:

```
structure(list(first = c(120L, 120L), second = c(1.33, 1.33), 
Name = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = "Pentanone", class = "factor"), 
Area = c(699468L, 153744L), Sample = structure(c(2L, 1L), .Label = c("PO2:1", 
"PO4:1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("first", "second", "Name", 
"Area", "Sample"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

The output should be:

```
structure(list(PO1.1 = NA, PO2.1 = 153744L, PO3.1 = NA, PO4.1 = 699468L), .Names =c("PO1.1", "PO2.1", "PO3.1", "PO4.1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `PO1:1<-ifelse(data$Sample=="PO1:1",data$Area, "NA")` is not legal R syntax (due to the colon in the first `PO1:1`)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "within the group." Perhaps you could show what the output of the program should be on your small dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As in the example in the quesiton, I am assuming `Sample` is a factor.  If this is not the case, consider making it such.*

#### First, lets clean up the column `Sample` to make it a legal name, or else it might cause errors

```
levels(myData$Sample)  <-  make.names(levels(myData$Sample))


## DEFINE THE CUTS##

# Adjust these as necessary
#--------------------------
  max.second <- 3  #  max & nin range of myData$second 
  min.second <- 0  #
  sprd <- 0.15     # with spread for each group
#--------------------------

# we will cut the myData$second according to intervals,   cut(myData$second, intervals)
intervals <- seq(min.second, max.second, sprd*2)

# Next, lets create a group column to split our  data frame by 
myData$group <- paste(myData$first, cut(myData$second, intervals), myData$Name, sep='-') 
groups <- split(myData, myData$group)

samples <- levels(myData$Sample)   ## I'm assuming not all samples are present in the example.  Manually adjusting with: samples <- sort(c(samples,  "PO3.1"))


# Apply over each group, then apply over each sample    
myOutput <- 
  t(sapply(groups, function(g) {

      #-------------------------------
      # NOTE: If it's possible that within a group there is more than one Area per Sample, then we have to somehow allow for thi. Hence the "paste(...)"
      res <- sapply(samples, function(s) paste0(g$Area[g$Sample==s], collapse=" - "))  # allowing for multiple values
      unlist(ifelse(res=="", NA, res))

      ## If there is (or should be) only one Area per Sample, then remove the two lines aboce and uncomment the two below:
      # res <- sapply(samples, function(s) g$Area[g$Sample==s])  # <~~ This line will work when only one value per sample
      # unlist(ifelse(res==0, NA, res))
      #-------------------------------

  }))

# Cleanup names
rownames(myOutput) <- paste("Group", 1:nrow(myOutput), sep="-")  ## or whichever proper group name

# remove dummy column 
myData$group <- NULL
```

#### Results

```
myOutput

        PO1.1    PO2.1    PO3.1 PO4.1            
Group-1 NA       "153744" NA    "699468"         
Group-2 NA       NA       NA    "32913 - 4948619"
Group-3 NA       NA       NA    "83528"          
Group-4 "536339" NA       NA    NA               
Group-5 "105598" NA       NA    NA
```

Comment: Ricardo, thanks a lot!!!!  Only one minor detail, is it possible to group the myData$second by values +- 0.15. For example, in this case 0.36 and 0.37 would be of the same group.  cheers

Comment: Sample was a factor as can readily be seen in the structure expression. (And @Francisco , you need to say how to operationalize that +/- request. If there were a bunch of items separated by 0.1 but spread over a wide range, how would the breaks be set?

Comment: @Dwin, yes, you are right.  I meant that I am assuming that the structure in the actual data is the same as that of the example. (Which, as you point out, it appears there may be more levels than are given in the example).

Comment: @Francisco:  I've edited the response to allow for grouping `Second` by range.  As DWin points out, you need to clarify the separations.  I've included three variables that you can adjust.

Comment: Thank´s DWin and Ricardo. My idea is to group if only the three conditions are present. Only group if values within first are equal, if values within second are +- 0.15 and if Name is equal. IN this case the breaks would be set by the Values and Name column limit. Is this possible? (I´m sorry not to state in the question that indeed there is a forth sample - PO3:1)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really expect R to intuit that there is a fourth factor level between PO2 and PO4 , now can you.

```
> reshape(inp, direction="wide", idvar=c('first','second','Name'), timevar="Sample")
  first second               Name Area.PO4:1 Area.PO2:1 Area.PO1:1
1   120    1.3          Pentanone     699468     153744         NA
3   126    0.4            Heptene      32913         NA         NA
4   126    0.4            Heptene    4948619         NA         NA
5   126    0.3        Methylamine      83528         NA         NA
6   132    0.5            Benzene         NA         NA     536339
7   132    0.5 Ethene._trichloro-         NA         NA     105598
```